# Timeseries: Groupby and calculate variance

Tags: pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, variance

I have the following dataframe with timeseries data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id', 'value'])
df['value'] =[9, 16, 10, 12, 11, 14]
df['id'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

For each timeseries (defined by column 'id' I want to calculate the variance to find timeseries that do not change at all or only very little.

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
df_end = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id','value', 'var'])
df_end['value'] =[9, 16, 10, 12, 11, 14]
df_end['id'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
df_end['var'] = [21, 21, 21, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3]
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby(df['id']).var()
```

which gives me the values, but I couldn't put it into the df in the right form. I am sure, there is a handy function for this that I don't know about yet!

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with specify column `value`:

```
df['var'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('var')
print (df)
   id  value        var
0   1      9  14.333333
1   1     16  14.333333
2   1     10  14.333333
3   2     12   2.333333
4   2     11   2.333333
5   2     14   2.333333
```